# iOS 10 video tag with "autoplay muted playsinline" stops background music (spotify)

Tags: ios, html5-video, ios10

I am trying to keep playing background music like Spotify playing with playing a inline video with attributs: "autoplay muted playsinline".

```
<video id="video" muted="muted" autoplay loop muted playsinline >
     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('video');
    element.muted = "muted";
}
</script>
```

But when I run this the video is plays inline and autoplaying. But as soon as the video start the background music app is pausing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer. You can't.

**One solution:**
is if you remove the sound track from the video. The background music like Spotify DO NOT stop playing.

Comment: Could you tell me which software you used to cut off the audio track?

Comment: I use HandBrake

Comment: Nice solution for remove audio you can use this online site too.
http://www.audioremover.com/